# How to connect streams with bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, stream, bloc

**How to connect the streams with Bloc in Flutter ?**

I tried to use streams in LoginBloc and the method there as well. Everything works perfectly till the part where I give event and use yield. Don't know why but here _emailController and _passwordController values are returning null. I tried: if I print them before @override method they are working fine and printing streamed proper values from Textfields they are closed. Im new to Bloc so maybe you can provide more information. Thanks

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:Octollenge/Data/Models/player.dart';
import 'package:Octollenge/Data/Repositories/playerRepository.dart';
import 'package:Octollenge/Logic/Blocs/auth/dispose/dispose.dart';
import 'package:Octollenge/Logic/Mechanics/validators.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

part 'login_event.dart';
part 'login_state.dart';

class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState>
    with Validators
    implements DisposeBloc {
  LoginBloc() : super(LoadingUserState());

  final PlayerRepository _playerRepository = PlayerRepository();

  final BehaviorSubject _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  final BehaviorSubject _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();


  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;

  Function(String) get changePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;

  Stream<String> get email => _emailController.stream.transform(validateEmail);

  Stream<String> get password =>
      _passwordController.stream.transform(validatePassword);


  Stream<bool> get submitValid => Observable.combineLatest2(
      email, password, (String email, String password) => true);

  //if I try to print here, before override using function it is okay, I get proper values
  //Ex. void func(){print(_emailController.value);} returns me proper value when I call it from any page using LoginBloc.func(); but not when I call it in bloc itself

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(
    LoginEvent event,
  ) async* {
    

    print(_emailController.value.toString() + ' email');
    //if I try to print here returns null

    if (event is LoadUserEvent) {
      yield LoadingUserState();
      try {
        
      } catch (e) {
        yield FailedToLoadUserState(error: e);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController?.close();
    _passwordController?.close();
  }
}
```

And Widget Login

```
import 'package:Octollenge/Builders/builder.dart';
import 'package:Octollenge/Logic/Blocs/auth/login/login_bloc.dart';

import 'package:Octollenge/Logic/Cubits/visible/visible_cubit.dart';

import 'package:Octollenge/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:progress_indicator_button/progress_button.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LoginBloc _loginBloc = LoginBloc();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        title: pacificoText(widget.title, 32),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
          create: (_) => _loginBloc,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                _emailField(_loginBloc),
                _passwordField(_loginBloc),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
                    child: routeText(context, 'Forgot Password ?', '/forgot',
                        Alignment.bottomRight)),
                loginButton(_loginBloc),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ubuntuText('Dont have an Account ? ', 16, Alignment.center,
                        Colors.white),
                    routeText(
                        context, 'Register', '/register', Alignment.center),
                  ],
                )
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordField(LoginBloc bloc) => StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: bloc.password,
        // ignore: always_specify_types
        builder: (context, snap) {
          return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24),
              // ignore: always_specify_types
              child: BlocProvider(
                  create: (_) => VisibleCubit(),
                  child: BlocBuilder<VisibleCubit, VisibleState>(
                    builder: (BuildContext ctx, VisibleState state) {
                      return TextField(
                          onChanged: bloc.changePassword,
                          obscureText: state.visibleValue,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorText: snap.error,
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                state.visibleValue
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                              ),
                              onPressed: ctx.read<VisibleCubit>().obscureText,
                            ),
                          ));
                    },
                  )));
        },
      );

  Widget _emailField(LoginBloc bloc) => StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: bloc.email,
      // ignore: always_specify_types
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24, bottom: 24),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: bloc.changeEmail,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorText: snap.error,
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
              hintText: 'Email',
            ),
          ),
        );
      });

  Widget loginButton(LoginBloc bloc) => StreamBuilder<bool>(
      stream: bloc.submitValid,
      // ignore: always_specify_types
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24),
            // ignore: always_specify_types
            child: BlocProvider(
              // ignore: always_specify_types
              create: (ctx) => LoginBloc(),
              child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                // ignore: always_specify_types
                builder: (ctx, state) {
                  return ProgressButton(
                    progressIndicatorColor: Colors.black,
                    color: snap.hasData ? primaryColor : disabledState,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                    onPressed: (AnimationController controller) async {
                      if (snap.hasData) {
                        controller.forward();
                        BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(ctx).add(LoadUserEvent());
                        state is LoadedUserState && state.player != null
                            ? Get.offNamedUntil(
                                '/accRouter', (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                                arguments: state.player)
                            // ignore: unnecessary_statements
                            // ignore: always_specify_types
                            : Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                                controller.forward();
                                controller.reset();
                              });
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ));
      });
}
```

Comment: Idk how to solve your problem, but this dude has great videos on bloc which helped me. Check these out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1P7q51rkPZw&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o-ZwjqAveM&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=5

Comment: In `Widget loginButton(LoginBloc bloc) `, why are you passing `LoginBloc` instance and at the same time creating new one i the provider in the same method?

Comment: @YoBo yes, thanks, it solved my problem ! I create new one that's why it comes as null

Comment: Actually I understood that this type of bloc pattern is not good. Better to do with videos that @rkdupr0n sent

Comment: Yeah... I was wondering why everything was declared in the Bloc instead of having separate code in Event and State files, lol. That entire series is great! U should give it a watch if ya have the time